# Can't execute correctly basic sas program

Tags: sas

I am a new learner of sas language. I know that this is easy for you. I just want to understand how does it work using macro variables. In fact , I just need to run a sas program correctly. I have tow marco variables 
&x=12,20,40,77
&y=12,45,54,78

I just need to compute the max and the min of them.So I write this code:

```
%let &x=12 20 40 77;
%let &y=12 45 54 78;
%put max min (&&x);
%put max min (&&y);
```

It shows me this error saying:

> Open code statement recursion detected

I tried to find solution but it doesn't work !how resolve it please?

Comment: Why?  The macro language is a text generation tool that is useful to product repetitive blocks of code with minor changes.  If you want to manipulate data then just use normal SAS code instead.

Comment: @Tom, I am learning the sas language. So I need to run simple examples to understand how work about macro variables!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the error you received you have probably confused SAS. The code you posted generates these errors:

```
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference X not resolved.
ERROR: Expecting a variable name after %LET.
1    %let &x=12 20 40 77;
2    %let &y=12 45 54 78;
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference Y not resolved.
ERROR: Expecting a variable name after %LET.
3    %put max min (&&x);
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference X not resolved.
max min (&x)
4    %put max min (&&y);
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference Y not resolved.
max min (&y)
```

In the first statement you are trying to create a macro variable by using the value of the macro variable X as the name of the macro variable. But X was never defined so `&X` just resolved to `&X`. Since `&` is not a valid character to use in the name of a macro variable you end up with an invalidly formed `%let` statement.

If we fix the first two statements so that they generate valid `%LET` statements then the code runs.  It is not clear what you wanted it to do but it works as SAS intended.

```
5    %let x=12 20 40 77;
6    %let y=12 45 54 78;
7    %put max min (&&x);
max min (12 20 40 77)
8    %put max min (&&y);
max min (12 45 54 78)
```

The extra `&` in the `%put` statements just make SAS have to take two passes to resolve the macro variable references. The first pass will resolve `&&` to `&` and trigger the macro processor to make another pass.  Then the second pass will properly resolve the resulting `&x` to the string `12 20 40 77`.

It is best to work with numbers using SAS code and not macro code. If you want to find the max of a list of numbers using the MAX() function. Normally you can use the `OF` keyword in data steps when you have values separated by spaces but that only works with variable names, not literal values.  So change the spaces to commas.

```
 9   %put &=x ;
X=12 20 40 77
10   data _null_;
11     max=max(%sysfunc(translate(&x,%str(,),%str( ))));
12     put max=;
13   run;

max=77
```

If you really want to stay in macro language only then use `%SYSFUNC()` function again to call the `MAX()` function.

```
14   %put max=%sysfunc(max(%sysfunc(translate(&x,%str(,),%str( )))));
max=77
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [link](https://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug02/ps/ps003.pdf)

I tried it around like this.

```
%let val1=17, 24, 35, 76; 
%let val2=87, 32, 45, 6;

data _null_;   
max=%sysfunc(max(&val1, &val2));   
min=%sysfunc(min(&val1, &val2));  
put max= min=;
run;
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate the same error as you have received.

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion but it doesn't work at all.Then I just compute the max and the min without using any intermediate function!